# Embedded DB for Firemonkey iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, database, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Are there any small footprint, embedded databases available for use to create iOS apps?

Comment: This is very close to being a duplicate of [Embeded DB for Firemonkey Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538602/embeded-db-for-firemonkey-apps). While `iOS` isn't in the question topic, there's an answer there related to `SQLite` that might be useful. Since `iOS` wasn't in the tags or text for that question, I have not voted to close this one as a dupe. :) And just as an aside: `FireMonkey` implies `Delphi`, as it's only for Delphi and C++ Builder, and they're compatible with each other in that regard. You don't have to mention Delphi (and you shouldn't put tag info in the title anyway)

Comment: @Ken, just out of curiosity, this answer at meta question: [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10651) suggest putting a key tag at the end of the title is acceptable. Are there more rules for writing good titles ?

Comment: @LURD, putting tag info in the title makes the title harder to read, uses space you could better use to describe your question, and makes the question title longer. I didn't say it was a *rule*; using tags is how things are designed to work, and the more info and clarity in the subject, the better your chances are you'll get an answer. (I have many tags in my list of "preferred" tags, one of which is `delphi`; any time a Delphi tagged question is posted, it's highlighted in the list of questions to catch my attention. I don't need "delphi" in the question itself to see it.)

Comment: For instance, this question could have been `Embedded DB for Firemonkey iOS apps?`, with the tags it has now, and it would have been easier to read, IMO, fit better in the list of questions, and  conveyed the same info. :)

Comment: @KenWhite, your suggested title is much better. Thanks for the clarification :)